# Помогите найти аналог globalStorage для Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пишу простое расширение для Chrome, которое уведомляло бы о новых постах на сайте.

Решил хранить в локальном хранилище номер последнего поста, который бы обновлялся при заходе на сайт, но столкнулся с проблемой: localStorage уникален для каждого домена и расширение не имеет доступа к данным, которые я кладу в localStorage при заходе на сайт.

Хотелось бы найти js-плагин, который бы реализовывал функционал globalStorage в Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

В качестве идеи, можно попробовать обойти ограничение на домены, создав расширение, которое будет включать [фоновую страницу](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), которая будет запущена вообще всегда, независимо от того, что открыто в обозревателе: пустая страница или страница какого-либо сайта. Эта фоновая страница будет обращаться к localStorage, а другие страницы расширения могут обращаться к ней.

Comment: Отлично, попробую реализовать.